# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at index-a136b960.js:3888:2474

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet, react-three-fiber, canvasjs

when i'm hosting my site it's not showing any content and given the error

"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at index-a136b960.js:3888:2474"

but this file are not available in my root folder or project, and when i'm run in this site localhos it's running as expected and not showing any error.

below this my json file in this project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZQqo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrcbi.png)

Live site link: https://nasa-space-apps-challenge-2023.vercel.app/

```
{
  "name": "first-3d-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@canvasjs/react-charts": "^1.0.0",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@material-tailwind/react": "^2.1.2",
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.85.2",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.14.4",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.35.7",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-three-fiber": "^6.0.13",
    "three": "^0.156.1",
    "vite-plugin-require": "^1.1.11",
    "zustand": "^4.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

how can i solve this

Answer (score 0):

As per details provided by you, i think you are not using any server to host the frontend build. Try to add a basic express server and serve your build content on it.

Comment: how can i add this?

Comment: as i said, create a basic express app and serve static file 
you can check this: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html and 
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

// Serve static files from the 'dist' folder (assuming Vite build output folder)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Serve the index.html file for all requests
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});


i'm creating express server like this but not working

Comment: have you set PORT in env?

Comment: keep it 443 if vercel generates https url or 80 if its http